# fe_sendauth: no password supplied when viewing http://localhost:3000/ after I launch rails s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have just installed the latest Rails on this mac and I have just run:

```
rails new testApp2 -d=postgresql
```

So once my new app is built I launched the rails server with:

```
rails s
```

But when I try to access the website on http://localhost:3000/ I get the following error:

```
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

In the extracted source it has stopped on the following line:

```
@connection = PGconn.connect(@connection_parameters)
```

I tried to follow some of the other solutions but they are extremely complex and I feel like I may be missing a piece of software or something much more simple. Please could someone give me a solution I can understand? With reasons.

In my database.yml I have the following:

```
# PostgreSQL. Versions 8.2 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On OS X with Homebrew:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
# On OS X with MacPorts:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: testApp_development

  # The specified database role being used to connect to postgres.
  # To create additional roles in postgres see `$ createuser --help`.
  # When left blank, postgres will use the default role. This is
  # the same name as the operating system user that initialized the database.
  #username: testApp

  # The password associated with the postgres role (username).
  #password:

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  #host: localhost

  # The TCP port the server listens on. Defaults to 5432.
  # If your server runs on a different port number, change accordingly.
  #port: 5432

  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # Defaults to warning.
  #min_messages: notice

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: testApp_test

# As with config/secrets.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password as a unix environment variable when you boot
# the app. Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full rundown on how to provide these environment variables in a
# production deployment.
#
# On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
# available as an environment variable. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="postgres://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# You can use this database configuration with:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
production:
  <<: *default
  database: testApp_production
  username: postgres
  password: <%= ENV['password'] %>
```

I could not get the postgres.app working because I kept getting an error that it would not run on this version of OSX (10.6.8) even though it stated it would work with this version. So I am running pgAdmin3 - which I think is similar.

Comment: What does your database.yml say? Where is your installation of postgresql? Do you have the `pg` gem installed?

Comment: Yes I have the pg gem installed. I am not sure where my installation is, how can I check?

Comment: I just don't understand - on my other computer I never had this problem so why does Rails now want a password. Will this happen on all my installations?

Comment: default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: testApp2_development

  default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

  development:
  <<: *default
  database: testApp2_development

  test:
  <<: *default
  database: testApp2_test


production:
  <<: *default
  database: testApp2_production
  username: testApp2
  password: <%= ENV['TESTAPP2_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>

Comment: Please do not post large code like that in comments, it is messy and should be added to your answer as an edit. Can you re-copy your database.yml into you question with the same formatting as the file? Thanks.

Comment: I posted the code into the answer.  If I start editing these settings will it not break the website when I push it to Heroku?

Comment: pgAdmin is an interface for talking to your DB. Postgres.app is the actual Postgresql database packaged for use on the Mac. You probably have the postgres server installed. Again, there is a very simple reason your other apps work and this one doesn't. You still haven't WHERE the postgres server is, though I'm guessing local. What username do you use when talking to it through pgAdmin?

Comment: Sorry. I haven't got any Rails apps working on this machine. I am on a new computer altogether I just never had these issues before.

Comment: Have you tried the answer I gave? You haven't really answered some of the questions posed here. What user name do you use in pgadmin to talk to the database for this app??

Comment: I am quite junior so I don't really understand this setup. So apologies if it takes me a while to understand. The server is local (I think). I am just trying to get Rails setup to run locally on this mac. The username appears to be 'postgres' according to pgAdmin3. Is this the information you need? I'm new to programming and finding it all quite overwhelming! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, that is very helpful. As I've stated in my answer below, you are trying to connect to the database with a user called testApp2. You need to know the password for that user and enter it into your database.yml file in the development section, or use the other answer provided below and change the security settings. You also did not post your entire database.yml.

Comment: I changed the user to postgres, which I got from the 'pgAdmin3' app. I still get the same error. I have updated my answer to reflect what I now have. Is there anything else I need to do? All I did upto this point was install a new Rails app - so I don't have a db built yet. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

change md5 (or whatever) to trust for your user, local connection in pg_hba.conf - this will allow you to connect without password...

Answer (score 0):

In your database.yml you have `testApp2` as your username. Normally (on a Mac at least) Postgres will create the user with the name of your account on your Mac. That is, if you log into your Mac with the username `andy` then the user for Postgres is `andy` with no password. It looks as if you have a user named `testApp2` in the DB or else it would have given you the error:

```
FATAL: role "testApp2" does not exist
```

So you have a user called "testApp2", you can create a password for this user and add it to your database.yml file. You can use `psql` to do this from the command line. Or you can change the user in `database.yml` to what ever your account name is on the computer as that user is already set up to be trusted without a password.

Comment: Some of this might assume you are Postgres.app on the mac. But I think it is still just related to using a user that requires a password vs. one that does not. Compare the database.yml from your previous app that you mentioned to your current one.